# Admob ad in Libgdx game is not visible

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

This is my code in MainActivity.java.

Can someone help me to fix this problem: I'm using eclipse and I test my application in a tablet. It works well, but the admob ads are not visible.

Why?

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams =
    new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //gameViewParams.bottomMargin = 150;
    requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    View gameView = initializeForView(listener, cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView, gameViewParams);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("Ad ID");
    //adView.setAdUnitId("app-id");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only big difference I see compared to my code is youradParams.

Try this:

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

Comment: thanks it works ,ths problem was that i didn't wait some seconds until the ad will be showing.

Comment: thanks my first code works well ,ths problem was that i didn't wait some seconds until the banner ad will be showing.but now i want to add both banner ad and an intestitial ad ,can you  help me please ?

Comment: this is my code in Activity_main.java look at the answer below